# Import to database/sftp

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, sftp

Could you please tell me whether the errors to connect to a server via Joomla 2.5 and simple PHP script mean the credentials provided are fault?

I used PuTTy to try SSH but the connection stops immediately. Files can only be uploaded via SFTP.

When trying to access PHPMyAdmin on the server, it tells that I don't have permission.

But with the following script it seems to connect:

```
    <?php

$strServer = "";
$strServerPort = "";
$strServerUsername = "";
$strServerPassword = "";

//connect to server
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);

if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword)){
    //Initialize SFTP subsystem
    $resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);

    //
    //Send/Download file here
    //
}else{
    echo "Unable to authenticate on server";
}

?>
```

I want to to import data from a SQL database to the newly created. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), provides better diagnostic abilities:

```
<?php
echo "BEFORE INCLUDE\r\n";
include('Net/SFTP.php');
echo "BEFORE DEFINE\r\n";

define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);
echo "BEFORE NET_SSH2 INITIALIZATION\\r\n";

$sftp = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
echo "BEFORE LOGIN\r\n";
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    echo $sftp->getLog();
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->getLog();
echo "LOGIN SUCCESS\r\n";
?>
```

Comment: In that case I'd be willing to bet you $20.00 you're getting fatal error (maybe because you don't have your include path's set correctly or something) and you have display_errors set to 0. Regardless, I've updated my post. Tell me what it says when you run it.